# Conditional Clause of add_custom_command

Tags: cmake

I want to take advantage of Ninja's "[job pools](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=job_pool)" in my custom commands; something finally directly supported in cmake 3.15.0.  Many/most people won't have this version, so I would like to simply ADD this support without requiring that anyone update their cmake version.

A more general question is...

*"What's the best way to specify a conditional clause of a custom command …?"*

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  foo
  COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch foo
  if("${CMAKE_VERSION}" STRGREATER_EQUAL "3.15.0")  # <-- syntax error
    JOB_POOL  my_job_pool                           # <-- syntax error
  endif()                                           # <-- syntax error
  VERBATIM
  )
```

Maybe...?

```
if("${CMAKE_VERSION}" STRGREATER_EQUAL "3.15.0")
  set(USE_JOB_POOL  JOB_POOL my_job_pool)
endif()
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  foo
  COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch foo
  ${USE_JOB_POOL}
  VERBATIM
  )
```

Or...?

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  foo
  COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch foo
  $<IF:$<VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL:${CMAKE_VERSION},3.15.0>:JOB_POOL my_job_pool>
  VERBATIM
  )
```

Comment: Both second and third ways are correct. Which one is used is up to you.

Comment: I forgot all about this post and a few months later, came back to attack the problem.  My efforts are captured here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896852/cmake-3-15-adding-job-pool-to-add-custom-command-sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Tsyvarev, my approach is reasonable.  In my code, which "works", I implemented something similar to this:

```
set(USE_JOB_POOL 0)
if("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" STREQUAL "Ninja" AND
   "${CMAKE_VERSION}" STRGREATER_EQUAL "3.15.0")
    set(USE_JOB_POOL  JOB_POOL my_job_pool)
endif()
...
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  foo
  COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch foo
  $<${JOB_POOL}:${JOB_POOL}>
  VERBATIM
  )
```