# cmake 3.15 adding JOB_POOL to add_custom_command SOMETIMES

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

For users that are using cmake 3.15 or later and are also using Ninja as a generator, I want to set the new JOB_POOL argument to some large [add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=JOB_POOL) blocks.  For other users, I want to keep my add_custom_command() the same (no JOB_POOL).

In earlier steps, I check the version and the generator and set ${JOB_POOLS} and I also set a variable such that users who should use a pool will see (something like):

**For historical reasons, I leave this here, although @Tsyvarev
points out that this is the source of my problem!
The double-quotes are NOT wanted here!**

```
set(USE_POOL "JOB_POOL pool_A")
```

Users that are not using a pool will not have that variable set.

Now how to leverage that variable in my custom command...?

1.) Generator expressions don't work, just including the text with the previous line...

```
add_custom_command(
  ...
  $<USE_POOL>
  )
```

2.) I can't seem to simply place the variable in the command, again just including the variable contents on the previous line.  For example, when ${JOB_POOL} is set to the string "JOB_POOL pool_A", this code...

**For historical reasons, I leave this here, although @Tsyvarev
points out that this is the source of my problem!
Don't use a STRING!  No double-quotes!**

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT foo
  DEPENDS bar
  # Comment line here...
  ${USE_POOL}
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E ...
  )
```

gives this error...

```
ninja: error: '../path/to/src/dir/JOB_POOL pool_A', needed by 'path/to/src/dir/foo', missing and no known rule to make it
```

It simply considers the ${JOB_POOL} string to be another dependency!

3.) I can't use the "APPEND" feature of add_custom_command().  It's just ignored...

```
if (${USE_POOL})
  add_custom_command(
    ...
    APPEND
    JOB_POOL pool_A
    )
endif()
```

The only thing that seems to work is to put an "if" around my
entire command, which offends my sensibility since I don't like to duplicate so much code...

```
if(${USE_POOL})
  add_custom_command(
    ...many lines...
    JOB_POOL pool_A
    )
else()
  add_custom_command(
    ...many lines...
    )
endif()
```

**Do you have a better idea...?**

Here's a standalone example for @tsyvarev:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project foo

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY JOB_POOLS pool_A=2)
# For historical reasons, I leave this here, although @Tsyvarev
# points out that this is the source of my problem!
# Don't use a STRING!  No double-quotes!
set(USE_POOL "JOB_POOL pool_A")

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  foo.out
  DEPENDS foo.in
  ${USE_POOL}
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy foo.in foo.out
  COMMENT "Converting foo.in -> foo.out"
  VERBATIM
  )
add_custom_target(foo-out
  DEPENDS foo.out
  )
```

```sh
% cmake -GNinja .
% ninja foo-out
ninja: error: 'JOB_POOL pool_A', needed by 'foo.out', missing and no known rule to make it
```

It considers the string to be a dependency...  If I move the USE_POOL to after the comment, it considers it part of the comment...  If I move it to after the command, it considers it part of the command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOB_POOL` *option* serves for the user's choice. You may create another variable which contains **sequence of related parameters** for `add_custom_command`:

```
if(JOB_POOL)
  set(JOB_POOL_PARAMS JOB_POOL pool_A) # Will add 'JOB_POOL pool_A' sequence of params
else()
  set(JOB_POOL_PARAMS) # Will add nothing
endif()
```

Then use new variable directly in `add_custom_command` call:

```
add_custom_command(
  ...
  ${JOB_POOL_PARAMS} # Will expand to additional parameters when needed
)
```

Comment: Sorry @Tsyvarev.  When I try this approach (as I tried to indicate above that I had), the contents of the ${JOB_POOL_PARAMS} variable are MERGED with the line above.  If it's a COMMAND, then it's garbage appended to the command.  If it's a DEPENDS, then it's a garbage that nothing knows how to build. If it's COMMENT, then I get garbage added to my comment text.  My point is that this approach seems reasonable *IF* I know what to put just before it.  What must be in place of "..." in your code box above?

Comment: "What must be in place of "..." in your code box above?" - The same as in the code in your question. Please, show the **exact** command you use. It is difficult to say what is wrong with it without viewing it. Also make sure that you run CMake exactly of 3.15 version (and have corresponded `cmake_minimum_required`).

Comment: You set the variable to `"JOB_POOL pool_A"`, but look into my code: there is **no double quotes** in it, neither in setting the variable nor in using it.

Comment: Thanks!  That's it!  I'm best bash scripting, so I'm always getting burned by things like ';' appearing, lists vs. strings, and that I think of as strings in "cmake" but aren't.